# Any SPICE library/API written in C?

Tags: c, api

I am looking for some implementation of SPICE (electronic circuits simulator) written in C language which can be used as library.

I found some [SPICE clone for Python](http://www.thedigitalmachine.net/eispice.html) and for [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438757/any-good-java-spice-library-api), but not for C.

So far, I am using [ngspice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/). It is very good clone of SPICE3, it is written in C, it has [very good documentation](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice-manual.pdf). Is it possible to use it as library (so I can compile it into shared library and use it in my C project)? I compiled ngspice from source, but the result is CLI interface. Is there any option I can compile it into shared library?

But I am fine with any other SPICE clone.

Comment: The text interface must talk to the rest of the code through some set of calls... So pull out the text interface, compiler the rest to a library and use the same API. Of course, you may find yourself having to reverse engineer the interface unless the internals are carefully documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Unix Way' would be to use the CLI program as is and use the 'system' standard library call to execute the binary (or fork/exec).  Much less work than what you are trying to propose and with the amount that you are going to be calling the external application the overhead of doing the system call will be negligible.

Comment: I like the "Unix Way", but is it really the "clean way"? Because everytime I want to change a variable or get another parameter from simulation, I have to call binary again. (In fact, `ngspice` can run in interactive and non-interactive mode. Is it possible to execute in interactive mode and work with stdin and stdout?)

Comment: Yes, you can use fork/exec with a pipe for stdin/stdout to execute the interactive program and send commands to it.  See: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/remap-pipe-fds.html.  And yes, it is the clean way; it's how Unix was designed.

Comment: Thank you. I will use this approach.

Answer (score 6):

ngspice now (mid-2013) now has an option to build as a shared library or dll to link into your app - it's documented in chapter 19 of the June 2013 manual (not the manual in the ngspice-25 release).

Comment: Is it possible to use the shared library dll of ngspice in android app? What would I need to accomplish this?